# Get All Functions, Classes, datatypes from Python

Tags: python

I am developing a small python learning app. where student simply searches for keywords like, `list`, `date` my app gives output as help text for keyword.

first i want to extract all python builtins, classes help text using help() into json file.
I tried:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules.keys()
['__future__', 'copy_reg', 'sre_compile', '_hashlib', '_sre', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', 'datetime', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'hashlib', 'abc', 'posixpath', '_random', '_weakrefset', 'errno', 'binascii', 'encodings.codecs', 'sre_constants', 're', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', '_warnings', 'math', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', 'encodings.__builtin__', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', 'codecs', 'readline', 'os.path', '_locale', 'sitecustomize', 'signal', 'random', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'sre_parse', 'os', '_weakref']
```

with above result i can extract

```
>>> bi = sys.modules.get('__builtin__')
>>> help(bi.list.append) (or)
>>> bi.list.append.__doc__
'L.append(object) -- append object to end'  # goes to json file
```

`sys.modules` gives `re`, `random`,etc. but **i didn't find `datetime`** in above list of modules. how to find all available functions, data types, classes etc from python?

Note: my goal is to extract help text as much as possible from python. not only sys.modules any method can be appreciated.

Edit: there is no datetime at first.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules.keys()
['copy_reg', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'abc', 'posixpath', '_weakrefset', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', 'encodings.__builtin__', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', 'codecs', 'readline', 'os.path', 'sitecustomize', 'signal', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'os', '_weakref']
```

After importing datetime sys.modules

```
>>> import datetime
>>> sys.modules.keys()
['copy_reg', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', 'datetime', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'abc', 'posixpath', '_weakrefset', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', 'encodings.__builtin__', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', 'codecs', 'readline', 'os.path', 'sitecustomize', 'signal', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'os', '_weakref']
>>>
```

Comment: I can see `datetime` in your result. 9th index.

Comment: sorry for that mistake. is sys.modules enough for like i mentioned in Note?

Comment: `'datetime' in sys.modules == False` on my machine eh.

Comment: Why do you want to *"extract help text as much as possible"*? It's all in the documentation.

Comment: FWIW, you can get a list of modules and other useful info via the interactive help command, `help()`, which you can run in the interactive interpreter, or via a script. And there's also the `pydoc` command.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question...

Comment: @PM2Ring i want to extract the information in seperate json file with keyword: "description" format. so that i can use that file in any language to develop my app.

Answer (score 3):

`datetime` is part of the standard library; its `datetime.datetime` type is not as built-in as list, which is a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

If you still insist on iterating through `sys.modules` rather than [looking it up](https://docs.python.org/2/library/), often [equally interactively](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+datetime), you might have to resort to [importing all standard libraries](https://github.com/jackmaney/python-stdlib-list/blob/master/setup.py#L13):
    import sys

```
from stdlib_list import stdlib_list

for lib in stdlib_list("2.7"):
    try:
        __import__(lib)
    except ImportError:
        continue

assert 'datetime' in sys.modules

print sys.modules.get('datetime').datetime.__doc__
# datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])
#
# The year, month and day arguments are required. tzinfo may be None, or an
# instance of a tzinfo subclass. The remaining arguments may be ints or longs.
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wanting to create your own version of `help()`, one that you deem to be in some sense more student-friendly. If so,  perhaps you can begin by going to the original. You could look at the source of `pydoc.py` (found somewhere like `C:/Python34/lib/pydoc.py`), where `help()` is defined. For example, the actual code for the help method begins:

```
def help(self, request):
        if type(request) is type(''):
            request = request.strip()
            if request == 'help': self.intro()
            elif request == 'keywords': self.listkeywords()
            elif request == 'symbols': self.listsymbols()
            elif request == 'topics': self.listtopics()
            elif request == 'modules': self.listmodules()
```

(followed by several more `elif` clauses)

You can start delving into the code for `listkeywords(self)`, etc.

Once you understand how `help()` locates its topics, then you can decide which to use.

By the way -- the code snippet from above indicates that simply typing `help('keywords')` etc. in the shell will go a long way towards answering your question.